# How to get local barcode scanner data into web application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, barcode-scanner

I'm building a web application with ASP.NET MVC4, it's some kind of repair case processing. There are several computers that will "run" the web application.

When there's a new part arriving, we want to get its serial number and put it in a form in the web page. Manually entering the code is prone to errors and therefore not an option.

Now I was wondering how one could connect an ordinary barcode scanner to a web application? As far as I know, there's no way to access any devices on the client pc from an HTML5-only web page. Did anyone face the same issue?

Of course, we could build a little helper tool with C# that runs on the clients and talks to the web app server, but that would render the whole thing rather unattractive.

Comment: Don't most such devices come with a keyboard driver that can type the scanned code into an ordinary input field?

Comment: Bascode scanners return some digits depending on the type. So, i believe that if the cusror is on the input textbox where you want to add the barcode, scan it (scanners not handhelds) and barcode will appear in the textbox. I have done it on win app. On web i believe it behaves the same.

Comment: That would be a way to go, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Our scanners can be configured to send an arbitrary prefix that we used to set the focus to the appropriate field automatically. Comes in handy if you also have multiple input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the Barcode scanner to work as a HID-device, it will then put the scanned barcode into the selected box on the application.

If it's a serial port scanner then you can probably use a KeyWedge application to accomplish the same.

If it's a Symbol/Motorola scanner you will find all the information you need on support.symbol.com.